# I am getting nullpointer Exception and DataStoreException when working with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new on hibernate but I have to made some changes on java code which is using Hibernate, when I tried to call the already written method I am getting exceptions. How can I solve this. the source codes and exceptions are here below.

In Class objListImpl I have following codes:

```
public List<String> getList(String source)
throws DatastoreException {
source srcs = RequestingSource (source);
Integer reqstSysID = srcs.getRqstrSysId();

String sqlId = "select destinationId from Destination where stat IN ( 'OBTN', 'DLVR', 'SYS' )";
return getHibernateTemplate().find(sqlId);
}



private RequestingSource findSource(String name) throws DatastoreException
{
    try
    {
        String sql ="from Source src where src.sysId = ?";
        List<RequestingSource> reqSrcList = getHibernateTemplate().find(sql, name);

        if (reqSrcList.size() > 1)
            throw new DatastoreException("Found more than one RequestingSystem for: "+ name);

        if (reqSrcList.size() == 0)
            return null;
        return reqSrcList.get(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("failed to find entry for: " + name, e);
        throw new DatastoreException("failed to find : " + name, e);

    }

}
```

In main class I have following Codes:

```
  objListImpl objList = new objListImpl();
List<String> IdList = null;

try {
        batchIdList = objList.getList("FILE");
    } catch (DatastoreException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to get the document");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I am getting following Exceptions on on console

```
  09:20:35,238 ERROR objListImpl:327 - failed to find : FILE
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.service.impl.objListImpl.findSource(objListImpl.java:318)
at com.service.impl.objListImpl.getList(objListImpl.java:441)
at com.service.impl.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:28)
Unable to get the document
com..service.DatastoreException: failed to find: FILE
at com.service.impl.findSource(objListImpl.java:328)
at com.service.impl.objListImpl.getList(objListImpl.java:441)
at com.service.impl.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.service.impl.objListImpl.findSource(objListImpl.java:318)
... 2 more
```

Comment: Which line is line 318?

Comment: List<RequestingSource> reqSrcList = getHibernateTemplate().find(sql, name); is in line 318.

Comment: How are you wiring in your Hibernate template?  It seems like `getHibernateTemplate()` is returning `null`.